# I can't add proper constraints to my container view in order to fit any device

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I've put some objects in 3 different horizontal stack views and then put them all a single vertical stack view. When I'm trying to add constraints like "Top Space to Safe Area", "Leading Space to Safe Area" and "Trailing Space to Safe Area" in order to make the objects fit on any device, they are not working as expected and it seems like the problem persists whatever I do. Help Please!

I will link some screenshots below:

- Here is the stack view with no constraints
  [image]
- Now there are alignment constraints and the constant value for the trailing one is 215 while the constant for the leading one is 16]
  [image]
- And this happens when I'm trying to make them fit equal on the any screen, they are not even well displayed on mine
  [image]

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want. Might be, you could change Distribution "Fill" -> "Fill Equally".

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to reply.

And I assumed your question is 'Why they aren't fill equally?'.

So the answer is to change the `stackView`'s `distribution` to `FillEqually`.

[image]

> If you want to learn more about auto layout, you can read this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html) first.